# process url's into application's output and strip them to create files with name of urls

Tags: bash

Created a script which makes use of an existing tool which process url's to get additional information.

now, this tool has an output format with the switch "-o" but due to the impossibility to create a filename with "output-$url-tool.txt", where the $url is a list which gets read line by line, thus: "http://www.something.com, (new line) https://www.something.com" etc.

Is it possible to strip the url while processing it to create a file with the stripped name "output-something.com-tool.txt" per url?

this might be a bit fuzzy to read but i kinda got lost and don't know any other way to ask this. im sorry.

see the example below for what i tried but obviously doesnt work due to the markup of the file.

`for url in $(cat /urls.txt); do tool -u $url -o output-$url-tool.html; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct you're using isn't particularly safe. Since `cat urls.txt` is split by whitespace, any whitespace accidentally in the file will break your processing. If you're sure you want to handle things line-by-line, use `read`.

You'll also want to quote your variables, and remove or modify characters which are not permitted within filenames.

```
while read -r url; do
  tool -u "$url" -o "output-${url//\//_}-tool.html"
done < urls.txt
```

And if you want to strip the method, you can do that with additional parameter expansion:

```
shopt -s extglob
while read -r url; do
  url="${url#http?(s)://}"
  url="${url%%/*}"
  tool -u "$url" -o "output-${url}-tool.html"
done < urls.txt
```

This uses `extglob` to make the `s` in `https` optional, and includes only the domain name in the filename buy stripping everything earlier in the URL, along with the entire path.

Note that `extglob` requires bash version 4 or above.

Comment: You have no idea how stupid i feel now.. but i'm thank and greatful for your answer! thanks a milion!